# Is the value of this determined by the lexical nature of the invocation of a function?

Tags: javascript

Is the value of `this` determined by the lexical nature of the invocation of a function?

```
function Foo() {}
Foo.prototype.bar = function() { console.log('this: ', this); }
Foo.prototype.bar(); // this: Foo.prototype
var fn = Foo.prototype.bar;
fn(); // this: Window
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "lexical nature", but yes, the value of `this` depends on how you call the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is the value of `this` determined by the lexical nature of the invocation of a function?

Yes, that's the case, but not for ES6 [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions). The environments they create don't have a `this` value. Instead, `this` will refer to the `this` value of the environment the function is defined in.

More info: [MDN - `this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)

Comment: No, I mean the lexical nature of the function invocation. i.e. the precise code symbols used to perform the invocation action. The interpreter actually checks how the invocation is being made (I presume), and sets `this` accordingly.

Comment: Yes, that's the case. I missed the "invocation" part. Updated my answer.